# wp_nav_menu limit items

Tags: wordpress, menu

I build a website with twenty eleven child-theme method, after adding 14 items to menu with Menus under Appearance in wp-admin, only 10 first items appear. I search around the internet and many people mention about adding suhosin to php.ini to solve it. I tried but it didn't help.

Anyone have the solution for it, please help me. I'm using bluehost.

Comment: can you provide the live site link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is, this **may be a CSS error** only. Your menu may be overflowed with 14 items or didn't get enough space to display all items in one line. Check your browser rendered source code first and make sure that all your 14 menus are listed there or not.

If all 14 items are there, then you need to reduce the font size or padding/margin between each element to accommodate all menu items in one line.

For a better check, provide us the live site link.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Here is the link to my website [link](http://maxwedding.vn/).
I'm sure the problem is not css or html code. You can detect and see the last <li> display but there's no content inside <li> tag. At this time, only 10 items can be added to this menu, if I add more, the rest will disappear (although the <li> still display)

Comment: Hi, But I can see all 14 menu items on your website. [Check this screenshot](http://s8.postimage.org/nsdq3fy5x/menu_items_SO.jpg). Also I checked in latest version of Chrome, Firefox and safari browsers. Every browser showing all 14 elements.

Comment: thank you. I fixed it by myself. My partner leave some code with `walker_nav_menu_start_el` function.
Thanks again for your support.